# Por que essa configuração de Tabs do Bootstrap não está funcionando?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

O código é o seguinte:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
     <title>Site</title>
     <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
     <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body > 


        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Pedido</a></li>
          <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Configura&ccedil;&otilde;es</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class ="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
            <p>Pedido</p>
          </div>
          <div class ="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <p>Confirguracoes</p>
          </div>
        </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Estão faltando o `bootstrap.min.js` e o jQuery. Ver [*Getting started - Bootstrap*](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GW77H/)</kbd>